# I can't get my background to display from CSS

Tags: html, css

**My folder had extra files in which I had not deleted and was causing me conflicts. Any other newbies like me out there, take note, a clean folder is the way to go. Thank you all for your time, effort & knowledge.**

> It seems my folder is messy and I might have conflicts. I am not
>   positive. But will clean up & see what happens. I will let you know
>   how it works out. Thank you so far for the help.

I have not done any web design for a few years and I was taught to do my layout in tables (Yikes). So if this is a proper noobish question I do apologize but I really can't figure it out. I can't get any background to display, I changed the way my directory link was written several times, I added the same picture to every possible section in the folder (It is still on my computer). I then cancelled it out & tried with just a back ground colour, which also doesn't work. I have been staring at this tiny bit of code for days now & reading advice but I have run out of things to try. I guess I have done something wrong but I am to stupid to see it.

I am using editplus.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Burn</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="shadow.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div id="backing">

<!------------------------------beginning of main pages header ------------------->
<div id="header"><img src="makedo.jpg" width="980" height="200px" border="0"/>
</div>
<!------------------------------Navigation bar ------------------------->
<div id="nav">
<p class="title"><img src="images/tabard.jpg" width="60px" height="60px"/><a href="#">Burn<span class="subtitle">-Aszune EU</span></a></p>

<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!------------------------------------main --------------------------------->

 <div id="main">
<h1>Burn Guild</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...</p>
</div>

<!-------------------------------------side bar--------------------------------->

<div id="sidebar">
<!-- Start HTML Code --><iframe WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="400" title="Shoutbox" src="http://shoutbox.widget.me/window.html?uid=npla79" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" ></iframe><script src="http://shoutbox.widget.me/v1.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- End HTML Code -->
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS is

```
#backing 
{
  background-image: url(../images/fire.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}



#nav
 {
background-color:#262626;
width:100%;
height:50px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 50px #5E5E5E;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
}

.title
 {
color:#EDEDED;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:25px;
width:350px;
margin-top:6px;
margin-left:150px;
font-weight:bold;
float:left;
}
.subtitle 
{
color:#EDEDED;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:15px;
}

#navigation
{
list-style-type:none;
}
li 
{
display:inline;
padding:10px;
}
#nav a
{
font-family:verdana;
text-decoration:none;
color:#EDEDED;
}
#nav a:hover 
{
color:#BDBDBD;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if your CSS is correctly referenced? Or have you tried simply adding the 'background-image' to the 'body' style instead?

Comment: try to add quotes maybe? background-image: url('../images/fire.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

Comment: I have had it in body & html. A separate Div was the last option I could think of.

Comment: o and the rest of my CSS works, just the back ground image and it is on the same sheet.

Comment: Note that background-size: cover; + background-attachment: fixed; makes Chrome bugs in some case and doesn't display your background.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either use `background-image:` with another manual properties for repeat and position or `background:` to add all the values in it.

In your case since you are using the background-image and all the values for it, it is not working so use only `background:`

```
#backing 
{
  background: url(../images/fire.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UcatuPuN/2/)**

Comment: This is how I originally had it but that doesn't work for me either. However someone else linked it with my code & it works for them.

Answer (score 1):

change your class #backing with below one in your css file

```
#backing 
{
  background-image: url('full path of your folder where file exists/fire.jpg'); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I even used this #backing 
{
background-color:#b0c4de;
}

Comment: I have only 1 CSS file.

Comment: You might actually be on to something, seems I have a messy trail (folder).

Answer (score 0):

For #backing change background-image to:

```
#backing {
    background: some-color some-url some-repeat-option some-position some-attachment-option;
}
```

and its ok, see here http://jsfiddle.net/Z7KMx/ As you can check here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp background-image as background-repeat etc is a sub-property of background.

```
background-color: some-color;
background-image: some-url;
background-repeat: some-repeat-option;
background-position: some-position;
background-attachment: some-attachment-option;
```

Of course you can do it that way too by declaring all sub-properties step by step but its too much pain i suppose so the shorthand version is by far better.

```
background: some-color some-url some-repeat-option some-position some-attachment-option;
```

Comment: I have done this also but it isn't working for me still. I clicked your link & it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in order for this to work you have to remove `background-image` add use `background` only. Here is a demo I created for you
[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/D28gp/)

There are many ways to resolve this. but i prefer this one.

```
#backing 
{
  background: url('../images/icons.png') !important; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have even tried to do just a background colour via my CSS. Someone else did it and linked me the results & it works for them. Maybe I should give it a try on the laptop.

Comment: then the problem has to do with your file structure. please makesure that you placed your images and css in a correct directory

Comment: Your correct. It seems I had not deleted some old files from when I went emo with my first attempt. All cleaned up and working much better. It does seem to only want to cover the same height as my header though but I fixed this with height: Thank you for your help. If you know of a better fix then using height in the #backing please let me know.